# How to remove extra white spaces using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got HTML element contains this:

```
  <!--Product Style-->  <div style="float: right; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 5px;">  P6C245RO </div>  <div style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 5px;">  Style </div>  <div style="clear: both; border-top: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216); padding-top: 4px;">  <!--Product Description-->  <div style="font-size: 11px ! important;"></div>  <div style="background: url(&quot;http://ii.armaniexchange.com/ArmaniExchange/images/en_US/global/globalgraphics/bullet.gif&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0pt 4px transparent; padding-left: 12px;">fine tonal striped fabric</div>  <div style="background: url(&quot;http://ii.armaniexchange.com/ArmaniExchange/images/en_US/global/globalgraphics/bullet.gif&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0pt 4px transparent; padding-left: 12px;">epaulettes and sleeve tab</div>  <div style="background: url(&quot;http://ii.armaniexchange.com/ArmaniExchange/images/en_US/global/globalgraphics/bullet.gif&quot;) no-repeat scroll 0pt 4px transparent; padding-left: 12px;">metal logo plate on the chest pocket</div>
```

When i read it using jquery i get the `.text()` contains a lot of spaces and /n in between the text but without the html tags.

How to remove all these white spaces and return the clean text using jquery or pure javascript?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
element.text().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

This uses a regular expression (`/.../`) to search for one or more (`+`) whitespace characters (`\s`) throughout the element's text (`g`, the global modifier, which finds all matches rather than stopping after the first match) and replace each with one space (`" "`).

Comment: +1 I misread the question. That will work great for spaces and newlines (what the OP said he needed). Be aware that some browsers don't quite implement `\s` correctly once you get into non-ASCII whitespace (http://thinkweb2.com/projects/prototype/whitespace-deviations/), but that's a niggle. :-)

Comment: You're missing your `g` (global indicator).

Comment: @patrick Yes, after adding the 'g' (global indicator), things worked perfect.

Answer (score 23):

For the string

```
"    this  is my   string       "
```

You probably want to make the excessive spaces single spaces, but remove the leading and trailing spaces entirely. For that, add another `.replace`

```
s.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s|\s$/g, "");
```

For

```
"this is my string"
```

**Update**

```
s.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim()
```

Thanks, @Pier-Luc Gendreau

Comment: You can remove leading and trailing whitespace with `.trim()`

Comment: Unfortunately, `trim()` is not bulletproof. Try it on the string I provided above.

Comment: Seems to work over here and looking at the [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill), it even looks for BOMs and non-breaking spaces! It does require IE9+ though.

Comment: Safari and Chrome (latest) are giving me extra spaces between the words. `"this  is my   string"`

Comment: Oh yes, like I said, it removes leading and trailing whitespace so it leaves you with a slightly cleaner implementation. `s.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim()`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: This was what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can remove all instances of congruent whitespace and newlines like so

```
// Note: console.log() requires Firebug

var str = '    this  is \n    some text \r don\'t \t you    know?   ';
console.log( str );

str = str.replace( /[\s\n\r]+/g, ' ' );
console.log( str );
```

Then to clean it up and apply it to your jQuery

```
$.trim( $element.text().replace( /[\s\n\r]+/g, ' ' ) )
```

Answer (score -1):

This code working fine, Here I have remove extra white spaces in TextEditor.

```
var htmlstring =   $("#textareaCode").html().replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g, "");
```

for more Deatils refer: http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-remove-nbsp-from-texteditor-in-jQuery/1226#.V0J-2fl97IU