# RegEx: How to remove extra white spaces / line breaks like the DOM renderer does (&nbsp; handling)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to "strip" all (somewhat) unnecessary whitespaces from the HTML markup.

Obj:
[image: nodeValue]

Render:
[image: render]

For a nodeValue like that, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2898231/294619) works perfectly well.

However, when having a non-breaking-space `&nbsp;` the browsers renders - as we know - differently.

Obj: [image: nodeValue]

Render: [image]

I want to "strip" the string just like the DOM renderer does.

What is the RegEx that does the Job? Are there other pitfalls where I might cut something that is actually "needed" rendering?

**NOTE:** I'm operating on `innerHTML`, so the client can't help me...

Comment: Do **NOT** use regexes to manipulate HTML. You'll just end up with a trashed document. Use [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) for such things, and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) for the reason why regex+html = BAD

Comment: @ MarcB I know, that I would get hit by the possibly most famous so thread sometime :) Don't worry, I know what I do...

Answer (score 6):

This replaces all two-or-more whitespaces with a single space:

```
myStr = myStr.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ');
```

However, this will break anywhere you have a `<pre>` tag, or more generally anywhere that CSS `white-space:pre` is applied. To be valid, you'd need to `getComputedStyle()` on the elements in question and then only apply this transformation to the text nodes where the whitespace is not significant.

Comment: @AronWoost What? No, it doesn't, not if you are operating on the markup.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `/\s\s+/` with `" "` would do the trick.