# Removing whitespace between HTML tags with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, node.js

As someone who's not an expert in RegEx, how would I go about replacing extra whitespace between HTML tags with it?

Comment: The obligatory comment is that “regular expressions can’t parse HTML!”, but thinking about it, as long as you’re not trying to parse any structure out of it, this might be doable.

Comment: I'm not, I am using NodeJS and trying to do very basic whitespace removal.

Comment: Where did this string of HTML come from, and why does it have extra whitespace in it, and why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Use the answer posted by @Phrogz in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977962/regex-how-to-remove-extra-white-spaces-line-breaks-like-the-dom-renderer-does

Answer (score -1):

Here is another one you can sue:

[Remove whitespace and line breaks between HTML elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery)

Also try using a front-end build system like Grunt, Gulp or Make.  This will introduce you to uglify which will do that for you and compile everything into one file.  A good introduction tool is CodeKit.

Comment: does jQuery run on node.js now?

Comment: While I didn't include NodeJS as a tag, Dan is correct in saying that jQuery isn't quite as feasible on it. As well, I do uglify and compile everything as seen here: http://paulb.gd/